# How to sum numbers considered as strings?

Tags: r, string

I have a column in my dataset like this:

```
col1
1
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
1
```

I am trying to sum each row in a new column like this output:

```
col2
1
4
2
5
1
```

I have tried doing:

```
rowSums(as.numeric(as.character(df$col1)))
Error in rowSums(as.numeric(as.character(df$col1))) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In is.data.frame(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I am new to R and likely missing something obvious, but I can't find any similar problems online also in R to adapt to my data, any help or advice on what functions to use would be appreciated.

Data:

```
structure(list(col1 = c("1", "1, 1, 1, 1", "1, 1", "1, 1, 1, 1, 1", "1"), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Only 1s occur or also other integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sapply`. `strsplit` allows to get only digits you want, then convert them from character to numeric and sum then:

```
df$col2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$col1, ","), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
df$col2
```

> [1] 1 4 2 5 1

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to use `eval(parse)` after you replace `,` with `+`, i.e.

```
sapply(gsub(', ', '+', d3$col1, fixed = TRUE), function(i)eval(parse(text = i)))
#        1   1+1+1+1       1+1 1+1+1+1+1         1 
#        1         4         2         5         1
```

Another is to split and sum,

```
sapply(strsplit(d3$col1, ', '), function(i)sum(as.numeric(i)))
#[1] 1 4 2 5 1
```

However, If you only have `1` to sum, then you can simply count them. Using `stringr`,

```
stringr::str_count(d3$col1, '1')
[1] 1 4 2 5 1
```

Comment: I was to slow, this was my solution: ```df$col2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(X = df$col1, FUN=function(x){
  eval(parse(text= gsub(x, pattern = ",", replacement = "+")))}))```

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 separate_rows(col1, sep = ", ", convert = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 summarise_all(sum)

  rowid  col1
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     4
3     3     2
4     4     5
5     5     1
```

Or a quite handy option involving `splitstackshape`:

```
rowSums(cSplit(df, "col1"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

# assumes we are only summing integers, ignores decimals
sapply(str_extract_all(df$col1, "[0-9]+"), function(x) sum(as.integer(x)))
[1] 1 4 2 5 1


# Assumes we are only looking for the integer 1
str_count(df$col1, "1")
[1] 1 4 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can read with `read.csv` and use `rowSums` in `base R`

```
rowSums(read.csv(text = df1$col1, fill = TRUE, header = FALSE), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 4 2 5 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("1", "1, 1, 1, 1", "1, 1", "1, 1, 1, 1, 1", 
 "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```